# Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Item ID]1'

Tags: vb.net

I am receiving this error when trying to delete data from the database.

**Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Item ID]1'.**

Can anyone help please? Thanks.

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    'Check for the selected item in the list
    If Me.dgvData.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Me.dgvData.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim intItemID As Integer = Me.dgvData.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Item ID").Value
            'Open the connection 
            If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cnn.Open()
            End If

            'Delete data 
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            cmd.Connection = cnn
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Product WHERE [Item ID]" & intItemID
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'Refresh the data 
            Me.RefreshData()

            'Close the connection
            cnn.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

```
change cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Product WHERE [Item ID]" & intItemID
```

to

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Product WHERE [Item ID] = " & intItemID
```

You forgot the equals sign